# Need to ssh and run a single command as part of a larger bash script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ssh, vmware

My script is basically a convenient way to do remote shutdown and wakeonlan. The script runs from my Raspberry Pi

Shutting down my desktop is easy, but when I shut down my home server, I first would like to turn off my seedbox virtual machine (which is running on my home server) by connecting to it via SSH and issuing "shutdown -h now"

```
           TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
           echo "$TIMESTAMP: shutting down seedbox virtual machine"  >> ${LOG_FILE}
           sshpass -p " " ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no lukesau@192.168.1.27
           sleep 5
           sudo shutdown -h now
           sleep 60
           TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
           echo "$TIMESTAMP: shutting down $TARGET"  >> ${LOG_FILE}
           net rpc shutdown -f -t 5 -C 'Shutting down in 5 seconds' -U lukesau%pass -I 192.168.1.99
```

The seedbox is a Mac OS X virtual machine running in VMware. Perhaps there is a better way to shut down a VM before shutting down the host OS

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works, ssh isn't going to read the following commands from your input file. You can specify the command to be executed right after ssh

```
sshpass -p " " ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no lukesau@192.168.1.27 \
  'sh -c  "sleep 5 ;  sudo shutdown -h now ; sleep 60"'
```

This is assuming that you want these 3 commands executed via the ssh and the rest "locally" again.

I don't take guarantee for the quoting, nor for you sshpass construction as I have no manual for that.